# Having issue accessing a method from another method within a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I've created a simple class which I'd like to have return a model.

One of the methods is a simple normalizer which I'd like to be able to call from within another block of code. However it's not finding it. Here's what I have:

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        return
  
    def norm(self, train, x):
        return(x - train['mean'] / train['std'])

    def modelCreator(self, norm, df): 
        train = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
        test = df.drop(train.index)

        train_stats = train.describe()
        train_stats = train_stats.transpose()

        normed_train = norm(train)
        normed_test = norm(test)
```

However, when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
modelCreator() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'
```

(I was trying to call the modelCreator method directly and passing it a df)

I also tried to remove "norm" from the definition of modelCreator:

```
def modelCreator(self, df):
```

But in this case I get this error:

```
name 'norm' is not defined
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is it a *parameter*? Use `self.norm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `df` as a parameter to `modelCreator()`. You then access your `norm` method via `self.norm`. Below is your code updated.

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def norm(self, train, x):
        return(x - train['mean'] / train['std'])

    def modelCreator(self, df): 
        train = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
        test = df.drop(train.index)

        train_stats = train.describe()
        train_stats = train_stats.transpose()

        # These lines below are changed from original
        normed = self.norm(train, test)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've done just that and now I get this error: (norm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x')

Comment: Your `norm` method has 2 parameters, but in your implementation (and thus my copy-pasted version, now edited) you are only passing one parameter. If `x` is equivalent to `test`, then you can combine the last two lines of `modelCreator` to be `normed = self.norm(train, test)`

Comment: It wouldn't be equivalent though, since x is the value that I'd like to normalize in the dataframe.

Comment: Then you'll need to determine what your actual parameters need to be for `norm` and update accordingly, both the signature of the method and the calls to it to match.

Comment: Oh yeah that was exactly it! I was forgetting to pass the train df every time to the norm method. Thank you!